# How to run macro only on rows that the macro hasn't previously ran on

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have several sheets that copy rows from the "Master" sheet based on the condition of text found in column B. I've created a button on the Master sheet to run the following on each sheet that will be copied too.

If the "Master" is updated monthly how do I prevent rows that have already been copied to the 'KACC' sheet from being copied again when I run the macro?

```
Sub CopyRowsAcross()
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("KACC")

For i = 2 To ws1.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
    If ws1.Cells(i, 2) = "Kimborough Ambulatory Care Center" Then ws1.Rows(i).Copy ws2.Rows(ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to do a check on the KACC sheet that they're not there. The details of that check are hard to specify without more detail. Using autofilter would be quicker than your loop.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to check the KACC sheet?

Answer (score 0):

This custom function should work to see if a single row matches a range of rows by looping through each column. If they match, a `True` would be returned, or a `False` if anything is different.

Note that number of columns has to be the same, so it's probably best to include an entire row. The function takes into consideration end ranges so it shouldn't hurt your performance too much.

The `Exit Function` essentially mean no match (`False`).

There's probably some cell conditions I'm not thinking of (I did account for blanks), but hopefully you get the idea. If anyone has a more optimal approach, I'd be curious to see.

```
Function checkifRowexists(rowToCheck As Range, RngToCheck) As Boolean

Dim c As Long

If rowToCheck.Columns.Count = RngToCheck.Columns.Count Then

    For c = 1 To rowToCheck.Columns.Count

      If VBA.IsError(Application.Match(rowToCheck.Cells(1, c).Value, RngToCheck.Columns(c), 0)) Then

        If IsEmpty(rowToCheck.Cells(1, c)) Then
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(RngToCheck.Columns(c)) = 0 Then
                Exit Function
            End If
        Else

            Exit Function
        End If

     End If

    If Intersect(rowToCheck.Worksheet.UsedRange, rowToCheck.Cells(1, c)) Is Nothing And _
       Intersect(RngToCheck.Worksheet.UsedRange, RngToCheck.Columns(c)) Is Nothing Then
       Exit For
    End If


    Next c

    checkifRowexists = True
End If

End Function
```